# CPQ quoteline conditional custom action

Tags: cpq, conditional, custom-actions

I am trying to set up a conditional Custom Action on a CPQ Quote Line.  I only want the Desegment Line Custom Action to appear when a custom field "Segmentation_Editable__c" has a value of true.

I have tried setting up the Custom Action Condition to point to the Product, but that didn't work.  I also tried pointing it to the Quote Line, but that didn't work either.  The custom action always shows no matter what.

I have the following set up:
Custom Action

- Conditions Met: All

Custom Action Condition:

- Target Object: I've tried Product, Product2 and SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
- Field: Segmentation_Editable__c which is custom checkbox field on Product2 object.  There is also a same named field on SBQQ__QuoteLine__c object of type formula with the formula: SBQQ__Product__c.Segmentation_Editable__c
- Operator: equals
- Filter Value: true

The Custom Action appears in all scenarios.  Is there any way to get Custom Actions to be conditional at the line item level?

Mike

Comment: the custom action appears or disappears in the quote line editor or configurator. Are you talking about the same?

Comment: I am referring specifically to Custom Actions that are displayed on the Quote Line within the Quote Line Editor.  In other places, Custom Action Conditions have the desired effect of displaying or hiding the Custom Action.  However, Custom Actions displayed on the Quote Line within the Quote Line Editor do not seem to hide based on the Custom Action Condition.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Actions to be conditional displayed at the line item level, if you target the object to Quote.  Conditions that target object on quote can evaluate quote fields for custom actions that appear in the quote line editor or configurator.
Conditions that target object on Product can evaluate product fields only if your custom action appears in the configurator.

[Salesforce help Doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_custom_action_conditions_considerations.htm&type=5)

At the time of this comment, there isn't specifications I can find on how to have custom action conditions target object to be Quote Line. If anyone has information that could share, that would be appreciated.