# CPQ Custom Action Condition on QLE Line

Tags: cpq, custom-actions

[CPQ quoteline conditional custom action](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/268135/cpq-quoteline-conditional-custom-action)

Similar situation as above post but it seems it remains unanswered for a couple of years.

Has any one managed to figure this out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's [not supported](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_custom_action_conditions_considerations.htm&type=5) by Salesforce CPQ yet to conditionally render at quoteline level.

When Salesforce CPQ evaluates quote fields for a quote line custom action, the
action is either shown or not shown on all the quote lines. Custom actions can't be conditionally shown or hidden on specific lines.